# Are breakaway headers the standard for interfacing when prototyping with these holes?

Tags: pcb

I have a board which has these holes in them for interfacing with other components. I would like to reuse this board in the future for other uses.

Is soldering breakaway headers onto these holes the standard for prototyping? If not, what other options do I have and where can i buy it?

[Breakaway headers](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/117) sold at SparkFun.

[image: Breakout holes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those connectors will probably be a loose fit in the holes, and they aren't very robust. 
Headers like [these](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/Connectors-Multipole/PCB-Interconnect/Double-row-PCB-header-plug-2.54mm-pitch./28945) are probably intended for use with that board.

They have 0.64 mm square pins. Check the hole size with the board supplier to make sure. I use 0.9 mm holes for those connectors on my PCBs.

They are available from other suppliers as 2x20, or use shorter lengths as they are end-stackable. You can attach ribbon cable, or use double-row sockets like [these](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/Connectors-Multipole/PCB-Interconnect/Double-row-sockets/76076) on a mating PCB.

Comment: I would recommend placing the headers into the board and plugging a mating socket over the pins before soldering. This will keep the pins parallel and keep them in place if the plastic carrier softens during soldering. An alternative is a 40 way IDC socket (as used on PATA disk drives) along with a ribbon cable salvaged from an old PC (assuming a 0.1" pitch of course).